# Slowness / Lag in beam streaming pipeline in group by key stage

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

#### Context

Hi all, I have been using `Apache Beam` pipelines to generate columnar DB to store in `GCS`, I have a datastream coming in from `Kafka` and have a window of 1m.

I  want to transform all data of that 1m window into a columnar DB file (`ORC` in my case, can be `Parquet` or anything else), I have written a pipeline for this transformation.

#### Problem

I am experiencing general slowness. I suspect it could be due to the group by key transformation as I have only key. Is there really a need to do that? If not, what should be done instead? I read that combine isn't very useful for this as my pipeline isn't really aggregating the data but creating a merged file. What I exactly need is an iterable list of objects per window which  will be transformed to ORC files.

#### Pipeline Representation

> input -> window -> group by key (only 1 key) -> pardo (to create DB) -> IO (to write to GCS)

#### What I have tried

I have tried using the profiler, scaling horizontally/vertically. Using the profiler I saw more than 50% of the time going into group by key operation. I do believe the problem is of hot keys but I am unable to find a solution on what should be done. When I removed the `group by key` operation, my pipeline keeps up with the `Kafka` lag (ie, it doesn't seem to be an issue at `Kafka` end).

#### Code Snippet

```
p.apply("ReadLines", KafkaIO.<Long, byte[]>read().withBootstrapServers("myserver.com:9092")
    .withTopic(options.getInputTopic())
    .withTimestampPolicyFactory(MyTimePolicy.myTimestampPolicyFactory())
    .withConsumerConfigUpdates(Map.of("group.id", "mygroup-id")).commitOffsetsInFinalize()
    .withKeyDeserializer(LongDeserializer.class)
    .withValueDeserializer(ByteArrayDeserializer.class).withoutMetadata())
    .apply("UncompressSnappy", ParDo.of(new UncompressSnappy()))
    .apply("DecodeProto", ParDo.of(new DecodePromProto()))
    .apply("MapTSSample", ParDo.of(new MapTSSample()))
    .apply(Window.<TSSample>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
        .withTimestampCombiner(TimestampCombiner.END_OF_WINDOW))
    .apply(WithKeys.<Integer, TSSample>of(1))
    .apply(GroupByKey.<Integer, TSSample>create())
    .apply("CreateTSORC", ParDo.of(new CreateTSORC()))
    .apply(new WriteOneFilePerWindow(options.getOutput(), 1));
```

#### Wall Time Profile

https://gist.github.com/anandsinghkunwar/4cc26f7e3da7473af66ce9a142a74c35

Comment: Beam uses a dynamic lateness configuration by default that tries to account for lag time it thinks your system has. I've noticed using GCP Pub/Sub as the source that my data goes through my entire Beam pipeline instantly if I don't do windowing, but has a noticeable lag after a window closes if I do use windowing. I believe it's using a noticeable lateness configuration when it sees windowing. Have you tried tweaking your allowed lateness setting, perhaps manually setting it to a very low value?

Comment: Are you using Dataflow or DirectRunner? Can you provide a snippet of you code? It can be related to some configuration of youe window

Comment: @rmesteves Added a code snippet. I am using dataflow.

Comment: @MattWelke I believe the default allowed lateness is 0, should I explicitly set it to 0?

Comment: @MattWelke I have tried setting it explicitly to 0, it doesn't result in any change.

Comment: @AnandSinghKunwar can you try following this? It may help you finding where is the bottleneck in your code https://medium.com/google-cloud/profiling-dataflow-pipelines-ddbbef07761d

Comment: @rmesteves As mentioned in the question, I have tried using the profiler and it hasn't really help. All I could find out was half of the time was going in the group by key operations. I'll try using the pprof and profiler here again and post the result here.

Comment: @AnandSinghKunwar I think the result of the profiler may help me to help you. By the way, can you explain what do you mean with "I suspect it could be due to the group by key transformation as I have only key" ? Actually, what exactly do you need to do and why did you use a GroupByKey?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209442/discussion-between-anand-singh-kunwar-and-rmesteves).

Comment: @rmesteves can we discuss in the chat as SO recommends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem indeed seems to be a [hot keys issue](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/joining-and-shuffling-very-large-datasets-using-cloud-dataflow), I had to change my pipeline to create a custom IO for ORC files and bump up the number of shards to `50` for my case. I removed the `GroupByKey` totally. Since beam doesn't yet have auto determination of number of shards for `FileIO.write()`, you'll have to manually choose a number that suits your workload.

Also, enabling streaming engine API in Google Dataflow sped up the ingestion even more.